# How to get full name of pod by name in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I have backend service description in skaffold.yaml similiar this:

```
...
deploy:
  helm:
    releases:
    - name: 'myapp-backend'
      chartPath: myapp-chart-backend
      values:
        APP_IMAGE: ...
      namespace: myapp-ns
      recreatePods: true
...
```

After cluster is up I have list pods and `kubectl get pods` return

```
...
myapp-backend-7dbf4b6fb8-kw7zv
myapp-backend-redis-646f454bcb-7thrc
...
```

I need full name of pod (`myapp-backend-7dbf4b6fb8-kw7zv`) to use it in `kubectl cp` command, which requires full name.
But this command I run in my bash script, so I need to get full name `myapp-backend-7dbf4b6fb8-kw7zv` by name `myapp-backend`.

Comment: Hi `oc get pods -o name` will list the name only

Comment: This probably shouldn't be part of your core workflow: every time you redeploy your image (or Kubernetes moves your pod to a different node, or your deployment scales up, or ...) you'll have to have to repeat this manual step.  Whatever you're copying in, it'd be better to include it directly in the image, or use something like a ConfigMap or a Secret that can include small files at deploy time.

Comment: @Suresh Vishnoi What is oc command? kubectl?

Comment: Sorry, you can replace `oc` with `kubectl` thus `kubectl get pods -o name`

Comment: Ok, by this command I have list of pods. But how I select only one, which is produced by myapp-backend? And not select myapp-backend-redis. By grep command (or other search command)?

Comment: @David Maze I understand your point, but my case require such method of copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know the name in the deployment ('myapp-backend' in this case), you can:

```
kubectl get pods --selector=app=myapp-backend -o jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}'
```

**Update**

Since I obviously don't have an access to your environment, I've rather provided a a general path for solution, you can fiddle with this command but the idea probably will remain the same:

1. call `kubectl get pods --selector=...` (Its possible that you should add more selectors in __your__environment)
2. Assume that the output is json. Here one nifty trick is to examine json by using: `kubectl get pods --selector=app=<myapp-backend> -o json`. You'll get a properly formatted json that you can inspect and see what part of it you actually want to get.
3. query by jsonpath only the part of json that you want by providing a jsonpath expression, for example `{.items[0].metadata.name}` will also work

Comment: In my `deployment.yaml` my selector app has `testapp` value, so I need use `--selector=app=testapp`. But some deployments use this pair app=testapp, so your command return several results.

Comment: Why don't you add one more label in deployment.yaml to uniquely select your app? That's what labels are for.

Comment: @Log Please see an update of my answer, hopefully it will make more sense.